# Formula field assistance

Tags: formula-field

Is there a way to create a formula field on the Account object that pulls all values in a picklist field from All related Contact records?
IE: Contact has a picklist field named "Program". I would like to create a formula field on the Account named Programs which lists all the values from the Program field of all Contacts related to it.

Answer (score 2):

No that's not possible with only a formula field. You will need to either:

1. create an APEX trigger on Contact for this, or
2. use a combination of roll-up summaries (1 for each of the programs, with a SUM of all Contacts having that program) and a formula field (rendering the program names based on the roll-up summary fields). This might not be a good option if you have many different programs

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestions. We don't have a developer on the team so I might try number 2.